# Start lein repl with commands from the terminal

Tags: shell, clojure, leiningen

I would like to write a shell script to start a lein repl and then provide some commands while still keeping the repl running.

For example I might want to do the equivalent of:

```
lein repl
(dev)
(setup)
```

I can pipe to the repl by `echo "(dev)\n(setup)" | lein repl` but the repl terminates afterwards.

Is there a way to get around this or another means of starting a repl and issuing commands from a shell script?

Comment: If you don't need lein, but only clojure, you can use the `-e` and `-r` command line options.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(echo "(println :hello)"; cat <&0) | lein repl
```

This prints the command - letting the REPL process it -, then "switches back" to stdin for input. You might have to interrupt the `cat` call after leaving the REPL, though.

Comment: Cool trick, xsc.  I use things like `2>&1` all the time, but didn't know that one.

Comment: Why not just `echo '(println 1)' | lein repl` ?

Comment: @AntonChikin This would cause the REPL to shut down after running the command, something the question specifically wants to avoid.